# Shared Element Transition from Recycelrview to Activity

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, transition

Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит? Что я не так делаю?
[скрин экрана](https://yadi.sk/i/z-9xvtQ14hqsUQ)

Listener

```
public interface NoteListener {
void onNoteClicked(Note note, int position, RelativeLayout noteLayout);
```

}

Adapter

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> noteListener.onNoteClicked(sortedList.get(getAdapterPosition()),
                getAdapterPosition(), relativeLayoutNote));
```

Методы вызова DetailActivity

```
public static void start(Activity caller, Note note, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(caller, DetailNoteActivity.class);
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            caller, noteLayout, "note");
    if (note != null) {
        intent.putExtra(NOTE, note);
    }
    caller.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onNoteClicked(Note note, int position, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    if (!isClick) {
        DetailNoteActivity.start(this, note, findViewById(R.id.rl_note));
        isClick = true;
    }
}
```

Item note

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rl_note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_2sdp"
android:background="@drawable/background_note"
android:transitionName="note">...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим путем возможно топорным, если есть другой способ напишите пожалуйста.
В MainActivity добавил следующее:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NoteListener {
...
private RelativeLayout noteLayout;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
noteLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl_note);
...
@Override
public void onNoteClicked(Note note, RelativeLayout noteLayout) {
    this.noteLayout = noteLayout;
    if (!isClick) {
        DetailNoteActivity.start(this, note, noteLayout);
        isClick = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации к методу [makeSceneTransitionAnimation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions#makeSceneTransitionAnimation(android.app.Activity,%20android.view.View,%20java.lang.String)) вам необходимо передавать само view из которого вызывается listener.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> noteListener.onNoteClicked(sortedList.get(getAdapterPosition()),
                getAdapterPosition(), (RelativeLayout) v));
```

makeSceneTransitionAnimation выбирает центром анимации положение view переданного в него.
Так же из-за этого вы не используете параметр `int position` в методе `onNoteClicked`, и следовательно его можно убрать.

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло. Все так же с первой позиции все происходит